# SpriteKit: Should I pan the camera or move the background?

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, game-engine

When building a game with SpriteKit, with a platformer game (like Doodle Jump for example), is it preferable to move the camera up, or the background nodes down ?

What is the standard practice in other frameworks ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**MOVE THE CAMERA!!!**

One of the weirdest things about 2D game engines is that it often takes them a series of versions to get a camera.

They should be born with them.

SpriteKit was no different, it took forever to get a camera.

Now that it has one, never ever think of not using it.

Will make your life a million times simpler.

I can think of no exceptions, but look forward to being proven wrong.

Answer (score 3):

move background was HOTFIX until proper cam support added.

use the cam. its easy and fun. no reason to not imo.